# If statement not properly working in java

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I have a question about if statements and defining integers.
In this code:

```
if(matches!=null) {t =1;
            for (String match : matches) {
                if (t == 1 && "one".equals(match)) {
                    testSound.start();
                    t = 2;
                    System.out.println("the value of t is" + t);
                } else if (t == 2 && "two".equals(match)) {
                    testSound.start();
                    t = 3;
                    System.out.println("the value of t is" + t);
                }
            }
```

If the first if statement executes and returns 2, and then match = "two", will the else if statement work? If not, how would I make it so that when I set t=2, it is actually t=2. Right now it's not working so let me know!

Comment: You're opening more brackets than you're closing.

Comment: What is the output now and what is the ouput youre expecting?

Comment: You might could avoid the bracket confusion by formatting a little better and by typing the closing immediately after the opening one so you don't forget later.

Comment: Just swap these two lines `t++;` and  `System.out.println("the value of t is" + t);`

Comment: Change the second if to `else if` unless the two conditions working together every time.

Comment: I think that half your problem is that you're not using a line per statement, which is usually not a good thing.  I've edited your code so that it's laid out "properly" and the problem, which dasblinkenlight has pointed out, becomes very obvious.

Comment: You are using the right value but printing the wrong one. (Anyone recognizing the similarity to the `for-switch` pattern? :D) Also, the code structure is simply wrong. A what are you trying to do with this btw?

Comment: Basically this is for speech recognition. I'd like the first if statement to happen before the rest can...

Comment: That's a bit different than what the code says. But what is the actual business logic? The snippet is - excuse me - not making any sense. Am I right assuming that "one" and "two" are textual representations of what could be matched with a known voice pattern? What does `t` stand for? (That's why you should never name anything "`t`")

Comment: t is currently an integer. I am using the integer to attempt to solve the problem of the first if statement starting before the rest, but for some reason t is not equal to 2 after the first if statement is over.

Comment: The only case that can be true is if the first `if` statement doesn't run either. BTW, a **debugger** is way more suitable for this situation than *StackOverflow*

Answer (score 3):

Everything works correctly: the `t++` executes before `System.out.println`, so by the time the `t` is printed its value is already 2, not 1. If you need `1` printed, move `t++` so that it comes after printing.

The second if statement is not executing after that because match is "one", not "two".

Comment: That was the point of the code (sorry if the question wasn't clear)... my question is why the second if statement isn't being executed.

Comment: The second line isn't being executed because of that, I have another thing that tests what the match is and it is "two" it must be something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `System.out.println("the value of t is" + (t++));`.
That way you will first print the value of `t` to the console than add 1 to its value.

Comment: ...and add confusion potential to the code. One might simply slip over the lines beginning with `System.out` and miss the fact that `t` is incremented. More or less the same problem as it is with *oneline `if` statements*, a harmful mistake often made by some juniors.

Comment: you can't be so strict about coding approaches... for me 1 line ifs are way easier to read, if ternary operator is possible even better...

Comment: A ternary operator is a completely different animal. It is designed for statements that are oneliners anyways. It has its place and can be used where it fits. A oneline `if` in contrast is a bad practice that should generally be avoided, is error prone and is definitely not the right way of shortening a long method. And I can (*reasonably*) be even more strict: one should not use identifiers like `t`, besides the very standard `i`,`j`,`k` loop variables. Moreover, `if` branching can often be avoided. In those cases they should be avoided.